# Authentication to google cloud storage from GSUtil

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-storage

Until yesterday i haven't encountered any problems with the gsutil tool, i had permissions to read and write but yesterday it suddenly began to say following whenever i try to run a gsutil command:

```
gsutil ls
Your "Oauth 2.0 User Account" credentials are invalid. For
more help, see "gsutil help creds", or re-run the gsutil config
command (see "gsutil help config"). Failure: unauthorized_client.
```

I am using the gsutil from inside .google-cloud-sdk:

```
which gsutil
/Users/jesperrix/.google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil
```

I tried running the gsutil config command which says following:

> It looks like you are trying to run
>   "/Users/jesperrix/.google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py
>   config". The "config" command is no longer needed with the Cloud SDK.
>   To authenticate, run: gcloud auth login Really run this command? (y/N)

I tried running the command and it didn't work then i tried running the cloud auth login and it also didn't work. When it asked me for the application id i tried using both the string id and the old number id.

The user i am trying to authenticate with is the owner of the project.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the problem by removing everything form my home folder named something with google then i ran the bash installation again to install the sdk from scratch:

```
curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash
```

Now it works as intended again. I still don't know what went wrong!